# Why private members of base class object still get assigned from derived one?

Tags: c++, inheritance

In the following code, `Circle` is a public inheritance of `Point`, in which the private members `x`, `y` of `Point` is inaccessible. But while assigning `Circle c` to `Point p`, I found `p` can actually get the right value for `x` and `y`. Why is this happening?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Point {
public: Point(float x = 0, float y = 0);
        void display();
private:
    float x, y;
};
Point::Point(float a, float b)
{
    x = a; y = b;
}
void Point::display() {
    cout << x <<'\t'<< y << endl;
}
class Circle :public Point
{
public: Circle(float x = 0, float y = 0, float r = 0);
private:
    float radius;
};
Circle::Circle(float a, float b, float r) :Point(a, b), radius(r) {}

int main()
{
    Circle c(10, 10, 15);
    Point p = c;
    p.display();
    return 0;
}
```

with the output:

```
10    10
```

Comment: Because every Circle is a Point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is object slicing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Circle::Circle(float a, float b, float r) :Point(a, b), radius(r) {}
```

Circle derives from Point, so in the Circle constructor line above when you call:

```
Point(a, b)
```

It is initializing the base class Point with the passed in values a and b, who's constructor assigns them to x and y.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have access to variables `x` and `y`, because they are private. But you have access to public method `display()`. `display()` is public method of class `Point` and have access to private variables.

In other words you can call the method `display()`, but can not directly access the private variables `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Line `Point p = c;` casts `Circle` object to Point [(actually, slices the object to Point)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) and invokes default assignment operator for Point class. Default assignment operator copies all values (and private data too) to new object.

see more [Copy constructors, assignment operators, and exception safe assignment](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access private members via Derived class , When you call display() function (which belongs to Point class ) it can show x and y . When you assume `Point p = c`  and invoking `p.display()` it still invoking Pointer class's method. Because Circle can see her parents' display() method. Make your display() method private and Circle can't invoke it.

Comment: Read about Getters and Setters .

Answer (score 0):

The `Point` members are accessible "within" the `Point` subobject of a `Circle`.

Since you didn't define a copy constructor for `Point`, copying a `Point` behaves like this:

```
Point(const Point& p) : x(p.x), y(p.y) {}
```

and since `Circle` inherits from `Point`, `c` can be converted to `const Point&`, and thus `Point p = c;` copies the `Point` subobject of `c`.
This is known as "object slicing".

(On an unrelated note, "a circle is a kind of point" is a strange relationship.)

Answer (score 0):

On this line

```
Point p = c;
```

You are calling copy constructor of Point:

```
Point::Point(const Point& p)
```

And because you can create reference to Base class from Derived class, your code is equivalent to:

```
Point &ref = c;
Point p = ref;
```

Now `p` will contain copy of `Point` part of Circle.

And because you initialized `Point` part of `Circle` object in `Circle` constructor like this:

```
Circle::Circle(float a, float b, float r) :Point(a, b), radius(r) {}
```

`Point(a,b)` constructor is called, which will initialize `Point` part of  `Circle` with paramteters `a` and `b`.